# Problems with OWFS over the w1 kernel module

Tags: 1-wire

I have a Series 2 Raspberry Pi. Running the 3.18 (wheezy) kernel. I got the w1 module (allows one-wire over gpio using bitbanging) to work, with both attached temperature probes showing up in `/sys/bus/w1/devices`.

I installed owfs (one wire file system) using `sudo apt-get install owfs ow-shell` and edited `/etc/owfs.conf` to look as follows:

```
# Sample configuration file for the OWFS suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main OWFS configuration file. You should read the
# owfs.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here.

######################## SOURCES     ########################
#
# With this setup, any client (but owserver) uses owserver on the
# local machine...
! server: server = localhost:4304
#
# ...and owserver uses the real hardware, by default fake devices
# This part must be changed on real installation
#server: FAKE = DS18S20,DS2405

# w1 devices
server: w1 = all
#
# USB device: DS9490
#server: usb = all
#
# Serial port: DS9097
#server: device = /dev/ttyS1
#
# owserver tcp address
#server: server = 192.168.10.1:3131
#
# random simulated device
#server: FAKE = DS18S20,DS2405
#
######################### OWFS     ##########################
#
mountpoint = /mnt/1wire
allow_other
#
####################### OWHTTPD     #########################

http: port = 2121

####################### OWFTPD ##########################

ftp: port = 2120

####################### OWSERVER ########################

server: port = localhost:4304
```

I created a `/mnt/1wire` directory, edited `/etc/fuse.conf` to set the `user_allow_other` option, restarted the owserver, and rebooted multiple times.

OWFS is up, I can hit the html page, but the sensors are not showing up.

Any ideas?

(Note:  I found an earlier set of questions here from 2012 referencing the fact that OWFS didn't work with w1 in the default kernel.  I believe this is no longer the case, as this page http://owfs.org/index.php?page=w1-project states at the bottom "Status w1 (now called wire1) is functional for UISB but slow."  Please do not refer me back to the 2012 question.

Comment: Can you read the devices correctly from /sys/bus/w1/devices?

Comment: Yes, both probes return valid temperatures (by doing `cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-xxxxx/w1_slave`) within the range I'd expect.

Comment: Is https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=781637#p781637 related?

Comment: That looks plausible.  Will investigate.

Comment: Nope, made no difference.  I've tried the two patches suggested there, and no luck.  The problem is the same - nothing listed in `/mnt/1wire`, and it takes a long time to even ls the `/mnt/1wire/bus.0` directory

Answer (score 1):

I had to download the latest owfs since apt installed owfs 2.9:
[owfs 3.1p1 here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/owfs/files/owfs/3.1p1/)

> Fixes for a w1 kernel driver change introduced in Linux-3.16-rc1

Installed fuse from https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse (since it wouldn't build owfs with owfs-fuse  without it)
did the

```
./configure --enable-owfs
make
sudo make install
```

installed owfs to /opt/owfs/
ran

```
sudo owfs --w1 -m /mnt/1wire --allow_other --debug -F
```